# How to active outlook add-ins(extension) automatic?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I develope a outlook extension(add-ins) and I did a `setup.exe`by `publish projetname`.

After I install `setup.exe` in another computer(windows), I have a problem, because my outlook extension(add-ins) is always inactive by defaut...Every time to start outlook, I need to active my outlook extension(add-ins) by myself...

How to let my outlook extension(add-ins) be active when the outlook is started? Thank you?

Answer (score 0):

That means your addin does something (like crashing) that causes Outlook to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps :

1. open regedit.exe and locate this registry entry:-

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DisabledItems
(Note: 14.0 this depends on the Outlook version you're using, 14.0 is for Outlook 2010, previous versions will have lower version and advanced version will have higher number)
Delete any Reg_binary keys (do not delete default)

2. Delete the DisabledItems folder and then restart the outlook